# python kivyMD pos_hint not working properly

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

The pos_hint on my MDTextfieldRound is not working, tried searching for answers but i can't seem to find anything, so please help.

```
MDScreen:
    name: "menu"
    MDBoxLayout:

        orientation: "vertical"

        MDToolbar:
            pos_hint: {"top" : 1}
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: app.callback(x)]]
            right_action_items: [["timer", lambda x: app.time()]]



        MDTextFieldRound:
            pos_hint: {'center_x' : 0.5, 'center_y' : 0.30}
            hint_text: 'Enter Website URL'
            size_hint_x: .8
            halign: "center"
            
            
        
        Image:
            source: "name.png"
            size: 3, 3
            halign: "center"
            
        MDBottomAppBar:

            MDToolbar:
                title: "Title"
                icon: "language-python"
                type: "bottom"
                left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: x]]
                mode: "free-end"
```

The pos_hint doesnt seem to work on any widget i add on the program
https://github.com/Twinxs25/python-application-prototype-1 here's the full code

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What are you expecting to see?

Comment: the MDTextFieldRound widget, when changing it's position the only axis it does move is from the X bot if i change the Y axis it wont move.

Comment: Have you tried adding `size_hint = None, None` into your desired widgets?

Comment: yes I tried, it didn't do anything.